# Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'data' Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode

I am facing a very staring error on Xcode 14. I am trying to fetch list from firebase table. Here is my code which works perfect and build is succeeded with no issue, but Xcode is showing this error "Value of type 'DataSnapshot' has no member 'data'".

**In Short:** I am saying that I can run app even though Xcode shows an error. I have attached the screenshot of Xcode behaviour.

I have tried with

1. cleaning project build
2. deleting drive data
3. reset package caches

Nothing is working for me. Any better solution how can I remove this error.

```
 database.child(tableName).child(userID).observe(.value) { snapshot in
            // 5
            guard let children = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot] else {
                return
            }
            // 6
            self.recipesArray = children.compactMap { snapshot in
                // 7
                do {
                    var recipe = try snapshot.data(as: RecipeModel.self)
                    recipe.id = snapshot.ref.key
                    return recipe
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                    return RecipeModel()
                }

            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: Are you saying you can run your app even though Xcode shows an error?

Comment: yes exactly, app is running with this error on Xcode 14

Comment: So it’s Xcode then. I see you have already done a few things, you didn’t include restart xcode but maybe you just didn’t add it to the list. I would just ignore it since it has no affect on anything and hope it either disappears by itself or wait for the next version of Xcode. I have had similar issues myself but they have never been very long lived.

Comment: yea i have restarted my Xocde and Mac also but it did't work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- I don't have any idea about the DataSnapshot, But the snapshot
  contains the data.
- The " snapshot.value " gives the data.

Check out the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I I wasn't aware of the button on the issues pane for "show only issues from open documents and recently built sources", but if you press it, the error will be hidden.

Additional information on this error:

I came across this error after refactoring a property. I moved it from a child class to the parent class.

For example the original:

```
class A {
    var id: String
    var name: String
}

class B {
    var settings: A
}

class C {
    var entity: B?


    func execute() {
        guard let value = self.entity?.settings.id else { return }
    }
}
```

after refactoring:

```
class A {
    var name: String
}

class B {
    var id: String
    var settings: A
}

class C {
    var entity: B?

    func execute() {
        guard let value = self.entity?.id else { return }
    }
}
```

It is the line in the execute() method that returns the error, complaining that value of type 'A' has no member 'id'.

If I look at the build log after refactoring it references the correct source file in the correct spot on disk, but shows the old source line with the error (number and horizontal position are correct for the original source file, which no longer exists in its original form, it has been refactored).

Also, if I delete a character the guard 'id' and put it back, the edit alone is enough to make the error go away for 1 build, but it comes back after that.

At no time does this stop the project from successfully building and executing and normal debugging works correctly.

You just can't get rid of this, AFAICT. When I'm done with the changes I am currently working, I'll delete this sandbox and clone it back, after that, I hope it is gone. I suppose its possible Xcode is caching stuff somewhere else but we'll see.

edit: one thing I left out is that there are also protocols for A, B, C, which have been correctly refactored as well.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34770582)